# svn access to a https repository: username / password always being prompted for

Tags: authentication, svn, https

I just moved my svn repository to a new server.

Previously I was accessing my repository via: svn://oldserver/yyy/zzz.
Now I want to access it via: https://newserver:8443/svn/yyy/zzz.

I used `switch --relocate` to re-point my source tree and this seemed to work well.

When I try to update the source I use:

`svn.exe update zzz --username myusername --password mypassword --non-interactive`

When I do it still asks me for the username and password (which if I re-enter works OK).

No matter what I do I can't get it to accept the username and password parameters.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am not using Visual SVN Server which may influence your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really a SVN god, but I assume you got the checkout working? What happens if you just type

```
svn.exe update zzz
```

in the root directory of your project?

Comment: OMG - That actually worked from the command line.
I am not sure that is going to help me with my automated build process (CC.NET) but will give it a try and let you know.
Thanks for the super quick response.

Comment: Hmmm, not much luck although it is interesting that the the removal of the parameters makes it ask the question.

Comment: Don't ask me why exactly it works, as I said, I'm not a SVN expert. :-) I just noticed that SVN seems to save the login data after a successful checkout. If you don't provide username/password afterwards it will fall back to its saved login data. I'm sorry that I can't help you with CC.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check the files under the `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\` (`$HOME/.subversion/auth` in linux) folder and if there is an auth entry for this project, and edit or delete it as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass --username and --password, you're telling Subversion to ignore the cached username/passwords, and use those instead. There's probably an error in the username and/or password (maybe caused by your shell?)